# I want to combine json rows in t-sql into single json row

Tags: sql, json, t-sql, ssms

I have a table

| id | json |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"url":"url2"} |
| 2 | {"url":"url2"} |

I want to combine these into a single statement where the output is :

```
{
    "graphs": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "json": [
                {
                    "url": "url1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "json": [
                {
                    "url": "url2" 
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using T-SQL, I've notice there is some stuff in postgres but can't find much on tsql.

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `JSON_QUERY` on the `json` column to ensure it is not escaped.

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  JSON_QUERY('[' + json + ']')
FROM YourTable t
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('graphs');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9c518a3861c8233b63aa1ac2acf256ee)